# Command not found in Linux machine

Tags: linux, fortify

I installed Fortify software in Linux using the user "Kiran". When I typed `sourceanalyzer --v` using the user "Kiran" I got:

```
Fortify Static Code Analyzer 19.2.0.0196 (using JRE 1.8.0_181)
```

But, when I searched using the user "root", I am getting command not found.

```
sourceanalyzer --v 
bash: sourceanalyzer: command not found
```

Can someone please help me on how to find the version using the root user or any other user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch to user "Kiran", fire the command:

```
which sourceanalyzer
```

It should give you the path to the binary named `sourceanalyzer`. Now, you can either use the full path to this binary after switching to root or you can add this path to the `PATH` environment variable for the user root.